# How does bitcoin core handle service flag spoofing?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, protocol

There are 5 service flags in [src/protocol.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/protocol.cpp):

```
static std::string serviceFlagToStr(size_t bit)
{
    const uint64_t service_flag = 1ULL << bit;
    switch ((ServiceFlags)service_flag) {
    case NODE_NONE: abort();  // impossible
    case NODE_NETWORK:         return "NETWORK";
    case NODE_BLOOM:           return "BLOOM";
    case NODE_WITNESS:         return "WITNESS";
    case NODE_COMPACT_FILTERS: return "COMPACT_FILTERS";
    case NODE_NETWORK_LIMITED: return "NETWORK_LIMITED";
    // Not using default, so we get warned when a case is missing
    }
```

```
/** nServices flags */
enum ServiceFlags : uint64_t {
    // NOTE: When adding here, be sure to update serviceFlagToStr too
    // Nothing
    NODE_NONE = 0,
    // NODE_NETWORK means that the node is capable of serving the complete block chain. It is currently
    // set by all Bitcoin Core non pruned nodes, and is unset by SPV clients or other light clients.
    NODE_NETWORK = (1 << 0),
    // NODE_BLOOM means the node is capable and willing to handle bloom-filtered connections.
    // Bitcoin Core nodes used to support this by default, without advertising this bit,
    // but no longer do as of protocol version 70011 (= NO_BLOOM_VERSION)
    NODE_BLOOM = (1 << 2),
    // NODE_WITNESS indicates that a node can be asked for blocks and transactions including
    // witness data.
    NODE_WITNESS = (1 << 3),
    // NODE_COMPACT_FILTERS means the node will service basic block filter requests.
    // See BIP157 and BIP158 for details on how this is implemented.
    NODE_COMPACT_FILTERS = (1 << 6),
    // NODE_NETWORK_LIMITED means the same as NODE_NETWORK with the limitation of only
    // serving the last 288 (2 day) blocks
    // See BIP159 for details on how this is implemented.
    NODE_NETWORK_LIMITED = (1 << 10),
```

Do bitcoin core nodes verify if a peer is bluffing about a service flag? Example: If a peer has `NODE_NETWORK` flag set but its a pruned node